# Download size limit CURLOPT_RANGE not work?

Tags: php

I have function to download remote file based on offset and limit.

```
function get_part_file($url, $offset, $limit){
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RANGE, ''.$offset.'-'.$limit.'');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $result;
}
```

I wanna download 1024 bytes from end but this function download whole file. So, how can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

If the remote host does not support Range headers, it doesn't matter what you do: you won't be able to download a specific range.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ch = curl_init(trim($remoteFile));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RANGE, '0-102399');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
$fp = fopen($filepath, 'wb');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_exec($ch);
fclose($fp);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.